# How to add checkbox inside material cell and retrieve the combination record using angular8

Tags: checkbox, angular-material, angular8

I need to add checkbox inside the angular material table which is formed by dynamic data. I am providing my existing code below.

edit.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (submit)="updateProduct($event)" novalidate>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of size" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
             <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
             <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
             <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
   </div>
   <div class="form-footer">      
      <div style="margin-top:2%; margin-bottom: 2%; text-align: center;">
       <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-upper" type="submit">Save</button>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger text-upper" type="reset" (click)="resetForm($event)">Reset</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

edit.component.ts:

```
size: any = [
    { columnDef: 'position', header: '#',  cell: (element: any) => `${element.position}`},
    { columnDef: 'size1',    header: '28', cell: (element: any) => `${element.size1}`},
    { columnDef: 'size2',   header: '30', cell: (element: any) => `${element.size2}`},
    { columnDef: 'size3',   header: '32', cell: (element: any) => `${element.size3}`},
    { columnDef: 'size4',   header: '34', cell: (element: any) => `${element.size4}`},
    { columnDef: 'size5',   header: '36', cell: (element: any) => `${element.size5}`},
    { columnDef: 'size6',   header: '38', cell: (element: any) => `${element.size6}`}
  ]

  displayedColumns = this.size.map(c => c.columnDef);



  dataSource: any[] = [
    {position: "Black", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
    {position: "white", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
    {position: "Blue", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
    {position: "Grey", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
    {position: "Red", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
    {position: "Pink", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false}
  ]
```

The output of the above code is coming like below.

[image]

Here inside column headers there are some sizes for each color those are present inside the 1st row. Here I need to add checkbox under each size and after selecting some sizes respective of some colors then the selected combination arrays will be fetched inside the submit function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following changes into your code. Add `mat-checkbox` into HTML and write logic to set the value into it.

**edit.componet.html**

```
        <form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="updateProduct($event)" novalidate>
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of size" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
             <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
             <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
               <mat-checkbox name="checkbox" *ngIf="column.columnDef !== 'position'" [(ngModel)]="row[column.header]" class="example-margin"></mat-checkbox>
               <div *ngIf="column.columnDef === 'position'"> {{column.cell(row)}}</div>
               </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
             <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
   </div>
   <div class="form-footer">      
      <div style="margin-top:2%; margin-bottom: 2%; text-align: center;">
       <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-upper" type="submit">Save</button>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger text-upper" type="reset" (click)="resetForm($event)">Reset</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**edit.componet.ts**

```
   size: any = [
        { columnDef: 'position', header: '#',  cell: (element: any) => `${element.position}`},
        { columnDef: 'size1',    header: '28', cell: (element: any) => `${element['28']}`},
        { columnDef: 'size2',   header: '30', cell: (element: any) => `${element['30']}`},
        { columnDef: 'size3',   header: '32', cell: (element: any) => `${element[32]}`},
        { columnDef: 'size4',   header: '34', cell: (element: any) => `${element[34]}`},
        { columnDef: 'size5',   header: '36', cell: (element: any) => `${element[36]}`},
        { columnDef: 'size6',   header: '38', cell: (element: any) => `${element['38']}`}
      ]

      displayedColumns = this.size.map(c => c.columnDef);



      dataSource: any[] = [
        {position: "Black", 28: true, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
        {position: "white", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
        {position: "Blue", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
        {position: "Grey", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
        {position: "Red", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false},
        {position: "Pink", 28: false, 30: false, 32: false, 34: false, 36: false, 38:false}
      ];

updateProduct() {
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
```

Please check the updated code. I have edited the code to get data on save button click.

Comment: yes, the layout came as expected but can you please give me some idea in which array i will get the checked combination values means if i will check black/28/30 and white/32/34 then those values will get fetched in submit button.

Comment: I have tested after checked any check box the respective header value not getting true.

Comment: Actually I am using `formControlName` not ngModule so that `ERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive. ` is coming. Can it be replace with formControlName ?

Comment: @satya Here you are not using any other input fields. So you can remove `formControl` and use `ngForm`. Please refer `html` code for this.